# DateTime object + hours|days|months from string method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have problem with adding time values to `DateTime` object. Controller action gets values from form:

- `task_form.start_at` - DateTime
- `task_form.remind_value` - String, e.g. `"2"`
- `task_form.remind_space` - String, e.g. `"minutes"`, `"hours"`, `"days"`

I want to send method like

```
remind_time = task_form.start_at + send("#{task_form.remind_value}.#{task_form.remind_space}")
```

but I get `NoMethodError: undefined method '2.days'`. There is any way to use method like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to invoke the method '2.days' on self (the controller, I guess), but you need to call the 'days' method on the integer object returned by *task_form.remind_value*

Try this:

```
remind_time = task_form.start_at + task_form.remind_value.send(task_form.remind_space)
```

Comment: brilliant idea
task_form.start_at - task_form.remind_value.to_i.send(task_form.remind_space)
and it works, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rails provides a [`Date#advance`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html#method-i-advance) method:

```
start_at = DateTime.new(2014, 9, 18)
remind_value = "2"
remind_space = "days"

start_at.advance(remind_space.to_sym => remind_value.to_i)
#=> Sat, 20 Sep 2014 00:00:00 +0000
```